# Internal Server Error when testing javascript with cucumber-rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, selenium, cucumber, capybara

I'm having a strange problem with the following cucumber test:

```
  @javascript
  Scenario: Successful sign out
    Given there is the following user:
    | id       | 1                    |
    | email    | a@b.com              |
    | name     | Joe Blow             |
    | password | please               |
    And I am signed in as "a@b.com"/"please"
    When I follow "Sign out"
    Then I should see "You are signed out"
```

Clicking on the "Sign out" link requires javascript emulation, so I tagged the scenario with the @javascript tag, which causes it to run in firefox using selenium. It seems to run fine and everything works, except soon after the sign in succeeds, the browser screen suddenly changes and says "Internal Server Error" before capybara has a chance to record the result.

I have seen other errors saying that this can be fixed by switching the transaction strategy to truncation instead of transactions, but this seems to be happening already, since Cucumber::Rails::Database.javascript_strategy is set to :truncation.

Comment: First guess, are you using subdomains in the project?

Comment: No, we're not using any subdomains.

Comment: Did your issue resolved?

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember if this was ever resolved.